# AJAX View Table Data Button Click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to display the contents of my query on the same page as the button that initiates the query  .

```
 <form action="action.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" class="button" id="mail-button" name='msubmit'      value="View Mail" />
```

At the moment the button sends me to action.php that contains the below code

// this is my action.php

```
if (isset($_POST['mail-button'])) {  // if the view message button is click

include('..\time.php');
include('..\db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);


$delete = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM notopen WHERE username= '".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."' AND value='1'");

$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE username = '".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."'");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
       //echo $row['id'];
       $id = $row['id'];
       $username = $row['username'];


$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE rcpuser= '".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."' AND senderid ORDER BY time DESC
  LIMIT 20");
// I WOULD LIKE TO DISPLAY THESE RESULTS BACK ON THE SAME PAGE AS THE BUTTON WHILE USING AJAX TO AVOID PAGE REFRESHING
echo  '<table border="1" width="500px">';
echo'<tr>';

echo '<table class="table table-fixed  table-bordered table-hover">'; 

echo "<tr><th>From</th><th>Message</th><th>Time-Date</th></tr><tr>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{



//echo $row['senderid']; // to reply back to sender
$senerid = $row['senderid'];
echo "<tr><td>"; 

echo "<a href=message.php?id=".$senerid.">Reply to : </a>";
echo $row['username']; // username of sender
echo "</td><td>";   
echo $row['message'];
echo "</td><td>";    
echo "time_passed"($row['time']);  //time_passed calling funtion

echo "</td></tr>"; 



}
echo "</table>";
```

The above displays the results in a table for viewing , Now I want to use AJAX so the result are displayed on the same page without reloading instead of the action for the button redirecting to the above code . I need help understanding how I can get my table to show back in the success on my script and how to correctly format . Here is my script below

```
 // I dont want to redirect  here, I want my script to execute and have  the results displayed back on this page
<form action="action.php" method="post">



  <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$('#mail-button').on('click', function() {
var info = $('#name').val();
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "action_mail_view.php",
data: {
  name: info
},
 success: function(response){                    
 $("#table_wrapper").html(response); 
 //alert(response);
  }

  });

 });

</script>


<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>  <input type="button" class="button" id="mail-button"   name='name'     value="View Mail" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
 <div id="table_wrapper"></div>
```

How can I achieve this please? By just clicking the button the query (action.php)is executed and no refresh (AJAX) and results from table displayed on same page as button . Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us this file `about_me_action.php`

Comment: It above , All I have at moment is it contains the query(s) and the if isset for the button once its click

Comment: about_me_action.php renamed to action.php in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your initial page where the form is, you need to add a wrapper where the table should be added. Something like `<div id="table_wrapper"></div>`, which will be empty at the beginning. Then, on ajax success, you just need to get the message the ajax returned to you and set it inside the wrapping div. So, the content on the first page would be:

```
<form id="mail-form" action="action.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="mail-button" name='msubmit'     value="View Mail" />
</form>
<div id="table_wrapper"></div>
```

And the ajax call:

```
$('#mail-button').on('click', function() {
    var info = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {
      name: info
    },
    success: function(status) {
      $('#table_wrapper').html(status);
     }
    });
});
```

If your action function returns the wanted result, you should be good to go.

UPDATE: Since it's a submit input, the form will get submitted and redirect to the action.php script, regardless of the ajax call. One way is to change the submit button to a regular one, like so:

```
<input type="button" class="button" id="mail-button" name='msubmit'     value="View Mail" />
```

A better way would be to catch the submit event of the form. The ajax request will be changed to this:

```
$('#mail-form').submit(function() {
    var info = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {
      name: info
    },
    success: function(status) {
      $('#table_wrapper').html(status);
     }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The return false would cause the event to stop after executing the ajax call, so it will prevent redirecting to the actions.php. You can also use the `event.preventDefault` for that purpose.

Note I added an id to the form html.

Comment: I'm getting the result to work but the button action is taking to action.php which displays the results I would like for the results to display on the initial page as the button , Your above code helps me understand how the table is obtained thanks for that

Comment: Oh, right, that's because it's a submit button. You can either change it to type="button", or catch the submit event of the form. Let me update the answer.